# How to display array of object which is having the earning details and deduction details using angularjs dynamically?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angular.js for my front-end,
[I am having some list of values in DB.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMN7.png)

Controller code:

I got below output in the console.
    console.log($scope.items);

```
$scope.items = [
  {
    salary_head_name : 'BASIC',
    salary_head_value : 15000,
    salary_head_type : 'E'

  }, {    
    salary_head_name : 'HRA',
    salary_head_value : 7500,
    salary_head_type : 'E'    
  },{    
    salary_head_name : 'Conveyance',
    salary_head_value : 1600,
    salary_head_type : 'E'    
  },{    
    salary_head_name : 'Med. Allow',
    salary_head_value : 1800,
    salary_head_type : 'E'    
  },{    
    salary_head_name : 'PF',
    salary_head_value : 1800,
    salary_head_type : 'D'    
  }
];
```

actually, it prints all the records.

Expected output in UI:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMUXD.png)

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: hi ,i am getting the array object which is having both earning and deduction heads in single array object, but i want display the earning heads and there amount in first two columns and deduction and there amount in 3rd and 4th column ... kindly can you help me out about this one ..?

Comment: have you tried any code for display table which you want?

Comment: yah i used simple ng-repeat to display list in table ..

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var items = [ 
      { salary_head_name : 'BASIC', salary_head_value : 15000, salary_head_type : 'E'},
      { salary_head_name : 'HRA', salary_head_value : 7500, salary_head_type : 'E'},
      { salary_head_name : 'Conveyance', salary_head_value : 1600, salary_head_type : 'E'},
      { salary_head_name : 'Med. Allow', salary_head_value : 1800, salary_head_type : 'E'},
      { salary_head_name : 'PF', salary_head_value : 1800, salary_head_type : 'D'} 
    ];
    
    var getPortion = function(label){      
      var sum = 0;
      var out = items.filter(function(x){         
        return x.salary_head_type == label && (sum += x.salary_head_value);
      });
      return { out, sum }
    };
    
    var es = getPortion('E');
    var ds = getPortion('D');
    for(var item of ds.out)
      es.out[ds.out.indexOf(item)].ds = item;      
      
    $scope.items = es.out;
    $scope.totals = [es.sum, ds.sum];    
}]);
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-app='app'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="head in ['Earnings', 'Amount', 'Deductions', 'Amount'] track by $index">{{head}}</th>          
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
          <td>{{item.salary_head_name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.salary_head_value | number : 2}}</td>
          <td>{{item.ds ? item.ds.salary_head_name : ''}}</td>
          <td>{{item.ds ? (item.ds.salary_head_value | number : 2) : ''}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td ng-repeat-start='item in totals' style='font-weight: bold'>Total:</td>
          <td ng-repeat-end>{{item | number : 2}}</td>          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ...  now i will try this one and let you know  .. :)

Comment: Thank you so much mate ... You saved my day ... its working as i Expected  ... :)Slava Utesinov